# Stand by travel on Korean Air via ICN

Tags: transit

Will Korean Air board a passenger connecting via ICN to NRT with a standby ticket to the USA on United?

Comment: Can you clarify where the pax is, what flights they want to take on KE, what flights they are standby on, and whether all flights are on the same ticket? I'm not sure if you mean pax has a standby ticket NRT->USA and wondering if KE will accept to fly the pax to NRT, or if pax has a standby UA ticket X -> USA and would like to take X -> ICN -> NRT on KE with that ticket (which does not seem to make much sense).

Comment: Pax is flying stand by from DPS-ICN-NRT with Korean Air, and connecting to United Airlines, stand by as well, NRT-LAX, US passport holder

Comment: All flights are not on same tkt, has one res for Korean flights and a separate res for United flight

Comment: In normal times with a passport giving visa-free entry into Japan probably yes. Nowadays with the Covid restrictions still in place in Japan I highly doubt so. What's the pax citizenship?

Comment: Please use the full version of a word before using an abbreviation. I was looking for what peace you meant, pax, before I saw the passenger explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know the passenger's citizenship, but without a valid visa for Japan I doubt so.

With the Covid restrictions still in place in Japan, the current rules (using a UK citizenship here, but it shouldn't change much for others) [are](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=gb&destination=us&transit=jp):

> #### Passport
>
> ##### Admission and Transit Restrictions:
>
> Passengers transiting through Tokyo (NRT) must transit on the same calendar day.
>
> #### Visa
>
> **Visa required.**
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers with a **confirmed onward ticket** for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Passengers transiting through Tokyo (HND) or Osaka (KIX) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 72 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Additional Information:
> Valid visas in expired passports are accepted if accompanied by a new passport.

(emphasis mine)

Here you have two issues:

- The ticket is not confirmed since it's standby
- The onward flight is on another ticket and a different carrier, and airlines have been known to ignore such tickets.

So passenger would need a visa for Japan to be allowed boarding, and such visas are quite difficult to obtain these days.